# Is apostrophe correct in teachers day?

Tags: apostrophe, capitalization

[Source](http://www.indiamarks.com/history-indian-teachers-day/)

For the compound noun teachers day, some people call it **teacher day** and some other call it **teachers' day**. However, I believe that apostrophe implies possession and so as a day cannot be possessed by a teacher but only devoted so I think it's incorrect to say **teachers' day** and instead **teachers day** should be used.

Also, is it compulsory to use **capital t(T)** when referring to teacher's day as:

> The day usually starts with a warm **T**eachers Day speech to thank the teachers for their contribution. Few traditional methods include gifting beautiful **T**eachers Day cards and gifts to the teacher as tokens of love and respect. Some students also select popular **T**eachers Day quotes to convey hearty messages to their teachers and leave it at their desk.

Comment: This reads like "Teachers Day" is the name of an event, rather than describing someone's day? Is that the case here?

Comment: It's not a compound noun - compounds are single words. I think It's arguable whether it should be the genitive "teachers' say" or "teachers day" where "teachers" is modifying "day", though the genitive seems correct to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused with the word 'possession' which is not *actually* **owning** something in all the cases especially when it is someone's day. They don't **own** the day, rather, those days are 'named' after them. It's similar to naming some street 'Michael Jackson Street' where the legendary does not *own it!*

Had it been named after a single person it could have been a singular apostrophe. Say - Valentine's Day. But here, we are talking about the masses and *their* day. So, 'Teachers' Day'.

And yes, it's mandatory to use the capital letter. Because, it's *a proper noun* given to the day. That said, all the 'days' celebrated will have their first letters capitalized.

In pronunciation, I don't think 'Teachers' Day' and 'Teachers Day' make any difference.

Comment: Well, I am not sure whether we should have any apostrophe at all. Why should we use apostrophe in this context?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh why would you say 'It's **his** day' and *not* 'It's he day?' You see a *sort of* possession there? Nevertheless, there is something called an attributive noun which goes without the apostrophe. Say: Cricket Team Coach instead of Cricket team's coach.